# curl xpost with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I have a problem with a JQuery ajax request, cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

When I send a curl on the command line it is working fine:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:3000/bridge/heatingCircuits/hc1/temperatureRoomManual -d '{"value":20}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

But with JQuery Ajax it is not working:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/bridge/heatingCircuits/hc1/temperatureRoomManual",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: '{"value":20}',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

I got the following Error Response:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: What is the response you get back in the console from this request?

Comment: response is: {"status":"ok"}

Comment: So what makes you think it's not working?

Comment: I get the error alert, and when I check the status in the command line it is not updated.

Comment: Note that I receive {"status":"ok"} response on the command line, not with the Ajax.

Comment: Ok, so if you're hitting the `error` handler I need to know the Http status code that's being returned. Please view the request in the network tab of the browser and edit your question to include the status code and message.

Comment: I have added my Error Response

Answer (score 0):

did you try ? :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/bridge/heatingCircuits/hc1/temperatureRoomManual",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    //contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {value:20},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

Comment: Now i did, but same problem.

Comment: or try to remove contentType instruction in ajax @MelisDekker i edited my post ;)

Comment: With the hostname it is working, and also with the network IP of the server. HTTP Request is client side isn't it? And then i need my network ip and not 127.0.0.1. Stupid Me. Thank you.